# Cannot find module "d3" error is displayed after i upgraded my project from ionic 2 to ionic 3

Tags: d3.js, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I just upgraded my from ionic 2 to ionic 3. but now it is stuck at splash screen with error:

> Cannot find module "d3"

here is my ionic info :

> Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
>
> ```
> Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
>
> Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
>
> Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
>
> Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
>
> ios-deploy version: Not installed
>
> ios-sim version: Not installed
>
> OS: Windows 10
>
> Node Version: v6.9.1
>
> Xcode version: Not installed
> ```

Package.json

```
{
          "name": "MyApp",
          "author": "",
          "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
          "private": true,
          "scripts": {
            "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
            "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
            "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
            "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
          },
          "dependencies": { 
             //dependencies starts here. have updated these according to ionic 3
            "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
            "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
            "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
            "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
            "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
            "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
            "@ionic-native/core": "^3.10.3",
            "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^3.4.4",
            "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
            "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
            "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.10.0",
            "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
            "angular2-moment": "^1.1.0",
            "google-libphonenumber": "^2.0.14",
            "ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
            "ionic-gallery-modal": "0.0.7",
            "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
            "ionicons": "3.0.0",
            "rxjs": "5.1.1",
            "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
            "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
          },
          "devDependencies": {
            "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
            "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.1.2",
            "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.1.2",
            "typescript": "2.1"
          },
          "cordovaPlugins": [
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
            "cordova-plugin-console",
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
            "cordova-plugin-device",
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
            "cordova-sqlite-storage",
            "cordova-plugin-x-toast",
            "cordova-plugin-camera",
            "cordova-plugin-compat",
            "cordova-plugin-image-picker",
            "cordova.plugins.diagnostic",
            {
              "id": "phonegap-plugin-push",
              "locator": "phonegap-plugin-push",
              "variables": {
                "SENDER_ID": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
              }
            },
            "cordova-plugin-appavailability",
            "ionic-plugin-deploy",
            "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing",
            "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation",
            "com.hutchind.cordova.plugins.streamingmedia",
            "cordova-plugin-contacts",
            "ionic-plugin-deploy",
            "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing",
            {
              "locator": "https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent",
              "id": "com.napolitano.cordova.plugin.intent"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation",
            "cordova-plugin-file",
            "cordova-plugin-file-transfer"
          ],
          "cordovaPlatforms": [
            {
              "platform": "android",
              "version": "",
              "locator": "android"
            }
          ],
          "description": "An Ionic project"
        }
```

Followed [this](https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-3-angular-4-upgrade-guide/) link for the upgrade

Comment: can you include package.json?

Comment: included  @suraj

Comment: I dont see d3 in your package.json..how did you include it?

Comment: it was never included in package.json . it was installed using :npm install d3@v3.5.17

Comment: even before upgrading , it was working fine , without being declared in package.json

Comment: do `npm install d3@v3.5.17 --save`. When you upgraded did you clear node_modules and do npm install?

Comment: this is the set of commands used :
npm install d3@v3.5.17
npm install -g typings
typings search d3
typings install d3 --save
npm install jquery
typings install dt~jquery --global --save

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install d3 to package.json.

```
npm install d3 --save
```

Install the type declarations from npm:

```
npm install @types/d3 --save-dev
```

You dont need typings. It is deprecated.

The same for jquery.

Comment: Property 'target' does not exist on type '{}'. 

 Property 'svg' does not exist on type 'typeof "node_modules/@types/d3/index" 

 Property 'layout' does not exist on type 'typeof "node_modules/@types/d3/index" 

these errors i am facing now

Comment: how are you importing?

Comment: import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as $ from 'jquery'

Comment: I think you installed v4... https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md looks like there are many changes.

Comment: You can install with npm install d3@version_number.. for types.. it should be there in @types/d3/v3 folder..Or refactor your code to use latest version

Answer (score 1):

used following set of commands to solve:

```
npm install d3@vSpecify_your_version --save
npm install -g typings --save
typings search d3 --save
typings install d3 --save
npm install jquery --save
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
npm install aws-sdk --save
```

Then delete the node_modules folder of your project and do npm install in your projects CMD/Terminal.